# What is the correct way to write this in set notation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, notation

I'm currently working on some homework for my Complex Variables course. I was given the following problem:

> What is the domain of definition of $f(z)=\frac{1}{i-z^2}$?

I get the correct answer, which is $z\ne \exp(\frac{i \pi}{4})$ and $z\ne \exp(\frac{i 5 \pi}{4})$. How would you write this in set notation? Is $\{ z: z\ne \exp(\frac{i \pi}{4}), \ \exp(\frac{i \pi}{4}) \}$ correct?

Thank you!

Comment: The simplest way is $\mathbb C\setminus\{\exp(\frac{i\pi}4),\exp(\frac{5\pi}4)\}$. It would also be technically correct, though more long-winded, to write $\{z\in\mathbb C:z\ne\exp(\frac{i\pi}4),z\ne\exp(\frac{5\pi}4)\}$, as long as you include the $z\in\mathbb C$ part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is almost right, you just need to state where $z$ is, i.e. $z\in \mathbb{C}$ so you get $\{z\in \mathbb{C}\: z \neq \exp{(\frac{i\pi}{4})}, z \neq \exp{(\frac{i5\pi}{4})} \}$.

You could write it in many other ways, for example $z \in \mathbb{C}\backslash\{\exp{(\frac{i\pi}{4})},\exp{(\frac{i5\pi}{4})}\}$.